# Bootstrap 4 tabs: get index number of clicked tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out which tab the user clicked on by its index, e.g. they clicked on the second of five tabs.

I can get the total number of tabs by adding an ID to the nav:

`this.numTabs = $('#myTabset').children().length;`

from the Bootstrap 4 docs, I can get the clicked tab:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
      console.log(e.target); // newly activated tab
    });
```

Which logs:

```
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profileS" role="tab" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
```

So I can get all aspects of the clicked tab, but how to get which "number" tab it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery .index() method like this...

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var idx = $(this).index('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
});
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/GeNHX340fc

Comment: I need to scope it to this particular tabset, as there are others on the page I'm not concerned with (so, for example, I'm getting "13" for the second tab)

Comment: Then use a parent selector within the index() that's specific to the tabset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the index of the currently selected tab, do the below

```
let tabIndexNumber = $('#myTab a[aria-selected="true"]').index('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
```

The id #myTab is the id of the bootstrap tab. It produces a zero-based numeric value, zero being the first tab.